# If $ 0<A <B$, is it true that $||A||_p < ||B||_p$ for all $p$ positive integer?

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I have got some questions regarding matrix norms and inequalities. We only consider square, nonsingular matrices in the following.

1. If $ 0<A <B$, is it true that $||A||_p < ||B||_p$ for all $p$ positive integer, where $||A||_p = \max_{||x||_p = 1} ||Ax||_p$?
2. Given $|C| \leq |A|$, is it true that $\rho(A^{-1}C) \leq \rho(|A^{-1}||A|)$, where $\rho(*)$ is the spectral radius of *?
3. Is there an constant upper bound for $\rho(|A^{-1}||A|)$?
4. Is there an upper bound(using some function of the condition number of $A$) for $||A^{-1}||*|||A|||$?

For question 1, I know it is true when $p= 1,2,\infty$. Can it be generalized to all possible $p$? For example, for the case $p =2$, apply $\rho(A) = \lim_{k\to \infty}||A^k||^{1/k}$(wiki search 'matrix norm'), and $0<A<B$ gives $A^k<B^k$ for all $k$ sufficiently large, we have 
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}||A^k||^{1/k} < \lim_{k\to\infty}||B^k||^{1/k}.$$

Comment: For matrices what does it mean $A<B $?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal For all entries $a_{i,j}, b_{i,j}$ in $A, B$, $a_{i,j} < b_{i,j}$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So what do you think the answer for $1$ is?

Comment: @I think it is true. But I can only see why in three cases. Not sure how to prove for all cases.

Comment: How did you prove it for the cases you mentioned? You can post an answer for at least the case $p=2$!!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Use the special property of 2-norm. See update.